# How to make a chained dot notation work for nested hash keys using Ruby Metapraogramming

Tags: ruby, rubygems, metaprogramming

I am writing a function `from scratch` which takes hash in a constructor. Note that in Ruby a constructor is a special method of the class that gets automatically invoked whenever an instance of the class is created. However, some of my RSpec tests are not passing or functioning `because I couldn't implement it in the code`.

**code**

```
class Config
  attr_accessor :a1, :a2, :a3, :a4

  def initialize(args)
    if args.is_a? Hash
      args.each do |k, v|
        instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) unless v.nil?
      end
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Invalid argument. Supply a Hash instead of #{args.class}"
    end
  end

  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    return nil if method_name.empty?

    if args.include?(method_name.to_sym)
      send(args[method_name.to_sym], *args, &block)
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Method `#{method_name}` doesn't exist."
    end

    super
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(method, include_private = false)
    args.respond_to?("get_#{method}_info") || super
  end
end
```

**rspec**

```
describe Config do
  conf = Config.new({a1: 'test', 'a2' => {'a3' => [20, 21]}, a4: {}})

  it 'should' do
    expect(conf.a2.a3).to eq([20, 21])
  end
end
```

I tried to inspect my code and run `puts conf.a2.a3`, I get:

> Uncaught exception: undefined method `a3' for {"a3"=>[20, 21]}:Hash

I will be glad if anyone could help with this. It works for `conf.a1` and `conf.a4`, but I certainly do not know how I could make it respond to chaining with dot notations such as `conf.a2.a3` and return the value appropriately. If you have other approaches to how I solve it, kindly show me the way.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? I see no reason to use method_missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test doesn't work because conf.a2 returns a Hash (which doesn't respond to the message a3). I can't tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but it looks like you could make your tests pass by ensuring that whenever you return a value that would have been a Hash, that value becomes an instance of your Config class.

One thing that's odd, is you have defined attr_accessors for a flat list of names, but you're accessing the names in a structured way, not as the flat list you've defined.

If you want to access your configuration in a structured way, how about something like this? Trying not to depart too far from what you have:

```
class Config
  def initialize(args)
    if args.is_a? Hash
      args.each do |k, v|
        next if v.nil?

        if v.is_a?(Hash)
          instance_variable_set("@#{k}", Config.new(v))
        else
          instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
        end
      end
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Invalid argument. Supply a Hash instead of #{args.class}"
    end
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    if name.to_s.end_with?('=')
      instance_variable_set("@#{name.to_s.sub(/=$/, '')}", *args)
    else
      instance_variable_get("@#{name}", *args)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem will be that you will not be able to assign/store new values to those keys. For example, if you test with `conf.a1 = 'stephen'` or `conf.a1 = { 10 => 11 }`, it will throw argument error `wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)`

Comment: I should still be able to assign hash value to an existing key and or a new key with a value.

Comment: I modified my answer to include detecting when your message ends in '=' and using that to assign. It's just a quick hack, but it might get you started.